# Appending JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I am am trying to append an element to a `<div>` of a page, but it is not working.

**Page1 (index.php)**

```
<a href=" another.php " id="p1id" type="button">Go to page 2</a>
```

**Page2 (another.php)**

```
<div id=p2id></a>
```

**JavaScript (jqtest.js)**

```
$.("#p1id").click(function(){
    $.("#p1id").append()
});
```

Comment: get rid of the `.` between `$` and your selector, for starters.

Comment: In Page2, you're closing a `<div>` tag with `</a>`. That's invalid. Also, just calling the `append` method with no argument is meaningless.

Comment: what are you appending? Why the dots? What does page 2 has to do with this?

Comment: you cannot append from one document to another without ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem

```
$.("#p1id").click(function(){
-^here
 $.("#p1id").append()
--^ here
});
```

remove the `.`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<div id="p2id"></div>
```

...

```
$("#p1id").click(function(event){
    $("#p1id").append();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

In addition:

1. You need to `append` something
2. It looks like you are using an anchor, `<a/>`, as a button. You will need to prevent the default action, which would be to load a page.

Answer (score 0):

You're also calling `append()` with no arguments. It needs a `content` argument.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

If your html is

```
<div id="p1id">A div<div>​
```

You can append like

```
$(function(){
    $('#p1id').click(function(e){
        var myP=$('<p class="myClass">New paragraph</p>');
        $(this).append(myP);
    });
});​
```

An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3bjNS/).